# Umbraco Website content issues

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have a strange problem with Umbraco

I have three websites locally using umbraco 6.2.5

Lets say they are Website1, Website2 and Website3

all three are using three different mssql databases.

Everything was fine until i finished third website.

when i browse locally the navigations are fine...they all connect to their respective pages from the database.

but then the problem started suddenly ..when i connect to the website1's backend.. the left hand side content pane
 showing the website2's content pages

similarly when i open website3 in browser it is showing the pages from the 
respective databases but the backend content pane is showing website2's content.

i have make sure that the databases are different in each case.
i think this is some caching problem but not sure...also not sure about the 
solution 
please help me

Comment: Did you copy one of the websites to create the others? When you do, you should make sure to only deploy a couple of the files in the `App_Data` folder. The rest are TEMP files and caches. The `App_Data\packages\` directory and `App_Data\access.config` files are the only files you should copy. The `packages` directory stores xml records of created and installed packages on your site. Not critical but nice to have. The `access.config` stores your public access settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try force reloading the cache:

```
Right mouse click on Content -> Republish entire site
```

Or by directly calling this url

```
http://<<yourdomain.com>>/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true
```

Comment: I have tried reloading cache....but unfortunately all the websites's content pages went to recycle bin from where I am not able to restore...the current  content node is loaded with all the pages from website 2